# Generate list, two components at a time

Tags: python

I want to generate an list of list, where one of the elements is consecutive numbers, and the other is all elements from a short, predefined set:

// Needed result:
`[['A', 1], ['B', 1],['A', 2], ['B', 2], ['A', 3], ['B', 3]....]`

I tried some variations of the list generation, but can not find a working solution:

```
[['A', x],['B', x] for x in range(1,100)]

[[key, x] for key in ['A', 'B'] for x in range(1,100)]
```

Comment: Just put the loops in the other order: `[[key, x] for x in range(1,100) for key in ['A', 'B']]`. That's the order you would write them if you did it with regular nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprenhesion should do it in one line:

```py
new_list = [[key, i] for i in range(1,100) for key in your_set]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way.

```
[[key, x] for x in range(1,100) for key in ['A','B']]
```